# How don't change '/media/' on heroku after "git push ..."

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, git-push

Help me please.
I have django app on  Heroku.
I want that after `$ git push heroku master` folder `/media/` on Heroku don't change.
Thank you.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: @SohaibFarooqi haha it is delete my media after push

Comment: @SohaibFarooqi i want that media - not change and not delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/media` is for user-uploaded files. These **must not** be stored in the Heroku filesystem.

Heroku creates a new dyno each time you deploy your code, as well as whenever you run a management command and at irregular times otherwise. Each new dyno has its own filesystem which is not shared with other ones and only contains the files from your git repo.

You must configure Django to upload media files somewhere permanent, such as S3.

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot!